# sort a List of Map<String, String> based integer value

Tags: java, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a `List<Map <String, String>>` which contains data such as IP address, rx packets, rx bytes.
eg

```
{key:address value:10.0.0.1, key:packets value:500, key:bytes value:20240}
{key:address value:10.0.0.5, key:packets value:20,  key:bytes value:260}
{key:address value:10.0.0.100, key:packets value:1000,  key:bytes value:503210}
```

How can i sort this List based on bytes?
I want one output like this:

```
{10.0.0.100, 1000,  503210}
{10.0.0.1, 500, 20240}
{10.0.0.5, 20,  260}
```

edit: I get my data from API(mikrotik API) which returns `List<Map <String, String>>`

```
List<java.util.Map<String, String>> results = con.execute("mikrotik command");
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: in the map I see 3 elements... what is the key, what is the val???

Comment: Show us your code where you define the maps and put data into them.

Comment: I suggest you use a custom class instead of a Map.

Answer (score 0):

To sort based on a value of a key in a Map you can do

```
List<Map<String, String>> listOfData =

listOfData.sort(Comparator.comparing(m -> m.get("bytes"));
```

In general, you should use a custom class in Java, rather than a generic collection like Map wherever you have lots of them with the same String keys

Answer (score -1):

instead of using a map create a Custom class for the data with setters and getters.Implement comparator interface

```
class MyObject implements Comparator<MyObject>{
    String ip;
    int rxPackets;
    int rxbytes;
//getters and setters for each element

@Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        return o1.getrxbytes.compareTo(o2.getrxbytes());
    }
```

Then use `Collections.sort(pass List<MyObject> here);`